# Microsoft Excel add-in performance issue

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

The further code works more or less fine at .xls and it is pretty slow at .xlsx. Where is the problem?

```
vector = activeSheet.Columns["A", Type.Missing];
double[] temp = new double[vector.Rows.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in vector.Value2)
{
    if (item == null)
        break;
    temp[i] = vector.Value2[i + 1, 1];
    i++;
}
array = new double[i];
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    array[j] = temp[j];
}
```

Comment: What do you class as "pretty slow" and I presume your files you are testing with are the same size..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tested it with the files both contain the same data. Processing .xlsx was considerably observably slow. I've just solved the problem, though I've been thinking about it since yesterday evening.

Comment: You may wish to add your solution as an answer to your own question so it may help others in the future.

Comment: Of course, I will add the code that after the 8 hours timeout. The problem was in the activeSheet.Columns["A", Type.Missing] line.

Comment: Xls has 65k row limit. Xlsx has millions. The code processes als rows in column A (65k vs millions) and slower

Answer (score 0):

This line contained a problem:

```
vector = activeSheet.Columns["A", Type.Missing];
```

I've changed the code above to:

```
double[] temp = new double[activeSheet.Rows.Count];
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < activeSheet.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var item = (activeSheet.Cells[i + 1, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
    if (item == null)
        break;
    temp[i] = item;
}
...
```

And now it works in a blink of an eye.
Thank you @Sayse and @Eddy for the advices.